# What is the different in Vue data function structure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm wondering what is the different between the following format, and is there a different effect:

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    name: 'John',
    phone: 12345
  }
}
```

Here's the other format:

```js
data: {
  name: 'John',
  phone: 12345
}
```

Comment: See this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Vue you might surely asked yourself the question “why must data be a function that returns an object, and not just an object?”

Especially considering that in some places, data is not a function, as you most probably see in the App component in several examples.

The explanation is that when the component is used multiple times, if it’s not a function, but a regular object, like this:

data: {
  name: 'John',
  phone: 12345
}

then because of how JavaScript works, every single instance of the component will share this property.
This is not what you want in 99.9% of the cases, and instead you must do:

data: function() {
  return {
    name: 'John',
    phone: 12345
  }
}

It might be non-intuitive at first, but once you accept this explanation and learn that it’s kind of harmful to your application, and a possible source of bugs, you’ll remember to always use a function for data.